# Neomutt isn't passing the message location or contents with the print command

Tags: shell-script, printing, mutt

I use a print script that I call in my `.neomutt/config` with

```
set print_command="/home/myself/.config/neomutt/print.sh"
```

It has worked in the past but I haven't had ocassion to print email in a while and it isn't working now. I have been tinkering with the script and it seems like neomutt is not passing the email message itself with the print command.

The `print.sh` script itself is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1" pdir="$HOME/Desktop" open_pdf=evince
# check to make sure that enscript and ps2pdf are both installed
if ! command -v enscript >/dev/null || ! command -v ps2pdf >/dev/null; then
    echo "ERROR: both enscript and ps2pdf must be installed" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# create temp dir if it does not exist
if [ ! -d "$pdir" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$pdir" 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Unable to make directory '$pdir'" 1>&2
        exit 2
    fi
fi


tmpfile="`mktemp $pdir/mutt_XXXXXXXX.pdf`" 

enscript --font=Courier8 $input -2r --word-wrap --fancy-header=mutt --encoding=88593 -p - 2>/dev/null | ps2pdf - $tmpfile
$open_pdf $tmpfile >/dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 1
rm $tmpfile
```

If I add `echo "INPUT: $1"` or `echo "INPUT: $input"`, all I see when the command runs is `INPUT:`. How do I ensure that neomutt passes the actual email to the `<print-message>` command?

Comment: 'enscript' and 'ps2pdf' are installed?

Comment: @ploth they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a lot of research and I found your old posts where you put your `print.sh` together but I have no idea where you initially got the `mutt.hdr` from which you are using in `--fancy-header=mutt`. You probably wrote the file yourself, but you didn't upload it. If you remove that argument your `print.sh` script is working again but I saw you [started to use a new print script with unicode support](https://gist.github.com/amandabee/cf7faad0a6f2afc485ee/revisions) anyway.

Comment: I spent a lot of yesterday trying to troubleshoot this and dial in something that works. I definitely cribbed the script from somewhere -- I'm usually better about crediting my sources so I can get back to them.